# Array type 'float [size]' is not assignable

Tags: c++

I have a template method in which I am trying to place Objects into an array. I keep on getting the title error though. Below is my following code:

```
template <class Object>
void SparseMat<Object>::showSubSquare(int start, int size) {
   for (int rowIndex = start; rowIndex < start + size; rowIndex++) {
      Object objectsInRow[size];
      FHlist<MatNode<Object>> wantedRow = matrix[rowIndex];
      for (iterator<MatNode<Object>> iter = wantedRow.begin(); iter != wantedRow.end(); ++iter) {
          MatNode<Object> m = *iter;
          objectsInRow[m.getCol()] = m.data; //ERROR
      }
      for (int colIndex = start; colIndex < start + size; rowIndex++) {
         if (objectsInRow[colIndex] == NULL) {
           cout << defaultValue << " ";
         }
         else {
           cout << objectsInRow[colIndex] << " ";
         }
      }
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

For reference, m.getCol() just returns an int, so that is not causing the error. Also, matrix is a vector of lists, and FHlist is a self implemented list with the same basic utility.

My usage of the template function is as follows:

```
typedef SparseMat<float> SpMat;

int main()
{
   SpMat mat(MAT_SIZE, MAT_SIZE, 0); 

   mat.showSubSquare(0, 15);
}
```

The exact error is "error C3863: array type 'float [size]' is not assignable"

Comment: And what is the template argument for `Object` when you get the error?

Comment: @aschepler a float

Comment: How about copy/pasting the complete error as well as expanding your example to show your actual usage? What compiler are you using? Variable length arrays are not standard. Consider a vector.

Comment: I edited my post to better show my usage/error. I am using Visual Studio. I will try using vectors and see if it works.

Comment: So you're saying, the before the error you're talking about you don't have `error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant`, because Visual Studio does not support VLAs.  Here is a simple example, like yours should be, that shows all of the errors you should be seeing. http://rextester.com/FEEP29886

Comment: Wouldn't this be fine because it's a template?

Comment: use std::vector - I hadnt typed that for a few hours, I feel the need

Comment: @Tas `size` is not a template parameter

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am getting error C2131 actually! For some reason, not all my errors were loading, but I see it now. Does this mean Visual Studio does not support how I am using arrays?

Comment: @M.M I can't remember Visual C++ ever supporting VLAs. You could do the trick with an array of size 1 as the last member of a struct and then allocating more memory for the array. I'd guess that still works, but not sure if it's undefined behavior or not to use it.

Comment: @avi1234 Yes, it means you can't have an array size that is not a compile time constant. A vector would work perfectly though.

Comment: Show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

the 'size' is not const for the compile time, this will cause a crash;

Plan A:

Change that with std::vector,

Plan B:

using "new type[size]"

Plan C:

```
template <int _size> // this is the const value for the compiling time
void func()
{
   type array[_size];
   // your code ...
}
```